# fgrep a regex in command line terminal

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to fgrep a regex in terminal like this across files in my directory
`fgrep -i ".*HTTP/1\.1\" (?\!200).*" *` but I am not getting any output.

The regex I want to grep is `.*HTTP\/1.1" (?!200).*` which should grep all occurrences of anything starting with anything and having *HTTP/1.1" anything but 200*; basically any HTTP response but 200.

I also tested the regex with online regex tester and it matches
`HTTP/1.1" 400`
`HTTP/1.1" 500`
`HTTP/1.1" 404`

Is there something wrong I am doing? How should I be doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fgrep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fgrep) is the same as `grep -F` *pattern*, which treated *pattern* as a fixed string, not a regular expression.

Assume you have GNU grep with PCRE support:

```
$ printf 'HTTP/1.1" 400\nHTTP/1.1" 500\nHTTP/1.1" 200\n' |
  grep -P ".*HTTP/1\.1\" (?\!200).*"
HTTP/1.1" 400
HTTP/1.1" 500
```

or POSIXly, using `awk`:

```
awk '!/HTTP\/1\.1" 200/ && /HTTP\/1\.1/'
```

Comment: The POSIXly variant will exclude any 2xx result code, not just 200. (Are there others, though?)

Comment: @tripleee: Yes, I gave it because it seem the OP want to exclude any success 2xx.

Comment: But the question specifically says "anything but 200".

Comment: But now you capture lines which do not contain HTTP/1.1 xxx at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have escaped "!" in your regex.

```
".*HTTP\/1\.1\" (?!200).*"
```

Comment: I get `zsh: no such event: 200` error when I put the regex that you have mentioned

Comment: `[06/Oct/2015:07:49:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 916` This is only one of the outputs I am expecting. There may be other lines containing same regex but may not be exactly the same.

Comment: I have modified it and I assumed you want to ignore "200" status code.

Comment: Yes, I don't want anything containing `HTTP/1.1" 200`

Comment: `.*\[\d+\/[A-Za-z]{3}\/\d{4}\:\d+\:\d+\:\d+\s+\+\d+\]\s*\"[A-Z]+\s+\/\s*HTTP\/1\.1\"\s*(?!200).*`

Comment: This is another solution

Comment: This is very specific to the line I have given above. Basically, I want any line that contains the pattern I am trying to search.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93651/discussion-between-mayur-koshti-and-agarwav).

Answer (score 0):

The legacy command `fgrep` (now POSIXly known as `grep -F`) is specifically the `grep` family member which *doesn't* support regular expressions. It searches literal strings, only.

Your regex is not valid for `grep` or `egrep` (aka `grep -E`) either, because you have used Perl regex extensions like `?!`. With GNU `grep` you can use them with `grep -P`.

```
grep -P 'HTTP/1\.1" (?!200)...' ./*
```

Notice also how the useless leading and trailing context is unnecessary, and how dot but not slash needs escaping. (It works without escaping, too, but theoretically matches stuff you don't want to match.)

Comment: You want to use `./*` or `-- *` to work with file start with dash.